# XHR and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

One of the method that I am testing sends a XMLHttpRequest to "http://localhost:4848/qrs/extension/schema?xrfkey=asdfasdfdf". I am getting an error which looks like this -

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4848/qrs/extension/schema?xrfkey=asdfasdfdf. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9875' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Now I understand that test are served on "localhost:9876", and trying access localhost:4848 is actually violating cross domain policy. I have seen the karma proxy settings and tried -

```
proxies: {
   '/qrs': 'http://localhost:4848/qrs'
}
```

But doing this actually serves my content from "http://localhost:9876/qrs/extension/schema?xrfkey=asdfasdfdf". But this way my client code will not work. Because client code directly sends XHR request to "http://localhost:4848/qrs/.....", but NOT to "http://localhost:9876/qrs/.....".

Any suggestion how can I solve this?

Also, wouldn't it be better to have an option to set different headers in the config file? At lest we know that we are talking about test here (I mean not in production).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?